# How to create a TextView background with two vertical coloured stripes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a textView with the following characteristics:

- a background color (red)
- in the middle of the text view, two colored verticals stripes (5dp wide each), from top to bottom, on blue and the other green ?
- the text centered vertically and horizontally; the padding around the text should cover the stripes

[image]

Is it possible to do it directly with a TextView or do I need to combine a container (red with the two stripes) and add a default TextView on top of it ?

Comment: Try NinePatch images.

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible without extending TextView.  Makes most sense to me to do it with compound views as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using just a Textview also , by using layerDrawables to create background for the textview , but it would be easier using a container.